# How to handle 401 error in Jetpack Compose with Flow?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

Can you share your case studies on the best handle 401 unauthorized? I tried to do it via corountine expection handler, but realized I'm starting to duplicate too much code in the view models.

My handler:

```
private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        when (exception) {
            is HttpException -> when (exception.code()) {
                401 -> {
                    _detailsState.value = DetailsState.Error(ErrorConstant.UNAUTHORIZED)
                }

                400 -> {
                    _reviewState.value = _reviewState.value.copy(
                        anonymousError = ErrorConstant.ANONYMOUS_ERROR,

                        )
                }
            }

            else -> {
                _detailsState.value = DetailsState.Error(ErrorConstant.BAD_REQUEST)

            }
        }
    }
```

It works, but like I said I have to duplicate an awful lot of code and literally check for 401 errors in every screen. I tried to make an interspector, but I don't really understand how to correctly send events from it to other viewmodels, as well as how to process it correctly

Comment: This does not have a simple answer but while you are asking this question, you are on the right track of becoming a good software developer. This is an architectural question. If you haven't already, start here https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html